# Typeorm Multiple DB Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Hello how are you? I'm trying to connect two different databases in a project. I'm creating one mysql and one postgres, using typeorm. But I'm not able to use mysql. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

ormconfig.json:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "postgres",
    "port": 5432,
    "host": "localhost",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "database": "first",
    "migrations": [
      "./src/database/migrations/firstClient/*.ts"
    ],
    "entities": [
      "./src/modules/firstClient/entities/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
      "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations/firstClient"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "connection2",
    "type": "mysql",
    "port": 3306,
    "host": "localhost",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "database": "second",
    "migrations": [
      "./src/database/migrations/secondClient/*.ts"
    ],
    "entities": [
      "./src/modules/secondClient/entities/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
      "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations/secondClient"
    }
  }
]
```

database/index.ts:

```js
import { createConnections, getConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

getConnectionOptions().then(() => {
  createConnections();
});
```

entities/Client.ts:

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ database: 'connection2', name: 'contacts' })
class Client {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id?: string;

  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar')
  cellphone: string;

  constructor() {
    if (!this.id) {
      this.id = uuidv4();
    }
  }
}

export { Client };
```

and in repositories/implementations/clientReporitory I import my entity:

```js
import { Repository, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { Client } from '../../entities/Client';
import { IClientsRepository, ICreateClientDTO } from '../IClientsRepository';

class ClientsRepository implements IClientsRepository {
  private repository: Repository<Client>;

  constructor() {
    this.repository = getRepository(Client);
  }

  async findByCellphone(cellphone: string): Promise<Client> {
    const client = await this.repository.findOne({ cellphone });
    return client;
  }
  async list(): Promise<Client[]> {
    const clients = await this.repository.find();
    return clients;
  }
  async createMultiple(contacts: Client[]): Promise<void> {
    const clients = this.repository.create(contacts);

    await this.repository.save(clients);
  }
  async create({ name, cellphone }: ICreateClientDTO): Promise<void> {
    const client = this.repository.create({ name, cellphone });

    await this.repository.save(client);
  }
  async update({ name, cellphone, id }: ICreateClientDTO): Promise<void> {
    await this.repository.update({ id }, { name, cellphone });
  }
  async delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.repository.delete({ id });
  }
}
export { ClientsRepository };
```

if I run typeorm migration:run passing the connection it does the migration in mysql and postgres

```sh
typeorm migration:run -c "connection2"
```

Comment: Two things: 1. To create the connections for the databases defined in ```ormconfig.json``` simply call ```const connections = await createConnections();```. See [this](https://typeorm.io/#/multiple-connections/using-multiple-connections) for more information. 2. To have a UUID primary key that is generated simply use ```@PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")```. See [this](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/primarygeneratedcolumn) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't fully understand what or where is the problem with your code :/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).